# Is there a way to print an clickable link to the console?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode

Is that generally possible? Is the console able to format a link so that it is clickable? i.e. a link that launches an application, or anything else when clicked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not unless your terminal supports it, and most terminals I know of don't support such a feature.  If your terminal *does* support hyperlinks, read up on its documentation -- there's probably some escape sequence analogous to [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for doing so.

Comment: And that's assuming that he's using a terminal and not Xcode. Xcode definitely does not support any such feature; the Run Log is plain text only.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, yes ✨ (kind of).

Select the URL in the Xcode console then you can find ***Open URL*** among services in the right-click context menu.

[image]